# Multiple Id's or a class to drill down highcharts

Tags: highcharts, drilldown

Can any one tell me that how to give multiple  id's to a highchart drill down or can i give a class to that for accessing multidynamic data, like i write the drill down id's below, can we write like this

```
- drilldown: {
               series: [ { 
                   id:'level1',
                   name: 'Level 1',
                   data: [
                       {name: 'Trees', y: 1},
                       {name: 'Plants', y: 2},
                       {name: 'Grass', y: 3},
                       {name: 'Deeper', y: 4, drilldown: 'level2', drilldown: 'level3', drilldown: 'level4' }
                   ] 
               }
```

Comment: Can any one help plz

Comment: Could you point us what you would like to achieve, that you need to use multiple ID / class?

Comment: Are you asking to do multiple drilldowns, such as data point drills down to data set 1, where a point there drills down to data set 2, etc.?

Comment: look at this link on how to structure you data for drill down.  there's a lot of way to do it, you can get the main id and use that to filter your data.  the way you do it is pretty hard. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown